# Fancybox thumbnail helper with next prev buttons and limit of visible thumbnails?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Is there an example for fancybox 2 that demonstrates usage of thumbnails with next and prev button for the thumbnails and a limit value for the amount of visible thumbnails?
By the way, this is not a wordpress implementation but one in custom Website (asp.net mvc).

My requirements are:
- Show a Maximum of 4 thumbnails (we have currently up to 12 thumbnails per Gallery)
- Show a prev and next button for the thumbnails that works independently from the next and prev Buttons of the Gallery. So, Scrolling through the thumbnails does not scroll the Gallery

Thank you for assistance
SkippingAdi

Comment: You need to provide minimal code for us to work and provide you a solution. A Demo in fiddle would be great...

Comment: Have a look at this example:
http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

There is an example called Thumbnail helper.
Thank you for help.